# Отображение в WinForm таблиц связанных один ко многим (Entity Framework Core)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Есть 2 таблица "Заказ" и "Продукты". Связь один ко многим. У заказа много продуктов.
Не могу никак правильно сделать при выборе заказа (клик на него) что бы во втором DataGridView отображался список продуктов которые должны быть в заказе.
Как можно лучше всего это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но код по загрузке формы только такой

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    db.Orders.Load();
    db.Products.Load();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Orders.Local.ToBindingList();
    dataGridView2.DataSource = db.Products.Local.ToBindingList();
}
```

Comment: создать событие на изменение выбора строчки в верхнем DGV (SelectionChanged наверное) и при изменении выбора строчки брать из записи айди заказа и выводить в нижнем DGV продукты для нужного заказа

Comment: `dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(...) {}` и вот тут прописываешь SQL запрос - `бла-бла-бла... where orderdId = *тут ты должен как-то получить айдишник выбранного заказа при выборе строчки в DGV*` и меняешь у `dataGridView2` `DataSource`

Comment: [Databinding with WinForms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/winforms). Там EF6, но суть та же.